# Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client because no repositories are defined

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, spring-cloud

I want to compile this Gradle project:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.springframework.org/release"
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

group 'org.example'
version '1.0.0'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.2'
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client"    
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix"
    compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But I get error when I try to compile the project:

```
Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
    project :
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Everything is on maven central https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client/3.0.2/

Comment: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/2020.0.2/

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you need to define the corresponding repositories. As I have used eureka-client in maven.. I can show you how the repositories are defined.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

You can find the correct way of using the same for Gradle.

Comment: Two things then.. either some error in the way you have defined it.. please check that or it is a version mismatch thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:3.0.3'
or implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:VERSION_NUMBER'